# The brekel2mbl add-on does not work ; I need help to fix it

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

Recently I've bought the kinect v.2 and the brekel pro face 2 because I wanted to make the retargeting of my face movements. To success with my goal I need to generate Brekel Pro Face 2 compatible shape keys for models created in MB Lab 1.6.1. I found an addon that makes this,it's here :

https://github.com/tofarley/brekel2mbl

problems are :

1. it does not work
2. I'm not a python scripter
3. the author seems to be disappeared from 2016 he does not care about his     creation
4. it is compatible with Blender 2.77a ; Brekel Pro Face 2.190 and Manuel     Bastioni Lab 1.3.0
5. I have already tried to contact two python programmers,they have accepted to help me,but then they are disappeared.

I'm using blender 2.79 ; brekel pro face 2.30 and manuel bastioni lab 1.6.1. I've already tried the script as is and it didn't work,because of this error :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1woNkIWdqs-Hvg4vgnKcgpsLzIrXJxGyI/view

The names of the shapekeys are changed on the brekel side and also on the MB lab side,so the script should be updated. As I said I'm not a python programmer and I haven't so much experience with blender itself,so I need that someone fixes the addon's errors. Right now I've created a list of corresponding shapekeys between those of the brekel pro face 2 (on the left) and those of the MB lab (on the right),so the addon should reflect these changes :

```
Eye_Closed_L : Expressions_eyeClosedR_max
Eye_Closed_R : Expressions_eyeClosedL_max


Brow_Up_L : Expressions_browOutVertR_max
Brow_Up_R : Expressions_browOutVertL_max


Brow_Down_R : Expressions_browSqueezeL_max + Expressions_browsMidVert_min
Brow_Down_L : Expressions_browSqueezeR_max + Expressions_browsMidVert_min


Lips_Stretch_L : Expressions_mouthHoriz_min
Lips_Stretch_R : Expressions_mouthHoriz_max


Lip_Lower_Down_L : Expressions_mouthLowerOut_max
Lip_Lower_Down_R : Expressions_mouthLowerOut_max


Lips_Pucker : Expressions_mouthOpenLarge_min


Cheek_Puffed_L : Expressions_mouthInflated_max
Cheek_Puffed_R : Expressions_mouthInflated_max


Jaw_L : Expressions_jawHoriz_min
Jaw_R : Expressions_jawHoriz_max


Jaw_Open : Expressions_mouthOpen_max


Frown_L : Expressions_mouthOpenAggr_max (0.5) + Expressions_mouthSmile_min (0.6) 
Frown_R : Expressions_mouthOpenAggr_max (0.5) + Expressions_mouthSmile_min (0.6) 


Smile_L : Expressions_mouthSmileR_max
Smile_R : Expressions_mouthSmileL_max
```

I've tried to change the shapekeys already on the addon's code without adding the combined shapekeys,because I don't know how to do it,but it didn't work,as you can see in the video below :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1a_2EsVUZgrCEK6KJX3xuqlbwVwdqBLTw

so,that's all. thanks.

Comment: Your first google drive link is incorrect (404)

Comment: I gave it a look... Shape keys names are not corresponding to the Python script, and the point is to know how to redefine the skey table (in line 54) so that the good shape key names are corresponding again (that should fix the point). But you will need the Brekel specs to do that. Do you know where to find them?

Comment: watch here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=On_DF6Z8xqw&t=584s

the author of that tutorial explains that to make the retargeting it needs to create 20 shapekeys identical to the brekel ones...

Comment: Marietto, ok. As far as I understand it, this is just matter of feeding the skey table appropriately (so that's for Python part: adding and/or modifying the table lines). But to go further you need to know which shape key corresponds to which... this may be long (and above the time I can spend on it). Hope that helps though.

Comment: I've already tried to change the shapekeys used on the old version of the addon with the new ones and it didn't work. Can you do it for me ? You know where to get the names of the new shapekeys : they are also on the message that I've created here.

Comment: I've found a guy who has been able to fix the errors inside the brekel2mbl script. Now,I can load the shapekeys correctly. They have the same names of the brekel shapekeys. The problem arises when I load the bvh file generated by brekel inside the lab...it gives an error and It is not loaded at all. Instead,I tried to load another bvh file,that its not generated by the brekel and it worked...it seems that the problem is inside the bvh file generated by the brekel.....this is the error that I get : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BQ8p1uCiLuJEGvPkU3r9JLyBq5zhT5_m